# Where can I find extra templates for pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-templates

I've been working on characters and my friend suggested to me [www.d20pfsrd.com](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates) for a list of templates.

However, I feel as though these are not all the templates that are possible within pathfinder.

In pathfinder terms: A template is a set of rules that you apply to a "monster" to transform it into a different "monster". All templates give precise directions on how to change a "monster's" statistics to transform it into the new "monster". Like changing a "human" to "Advance Human" by adding an advance template.

I wanted to know: **Are there are other templates given by the game, 3rd party publication or magazines that are not listed within the website itself that can be applied to characters, creatures, and so forth? If so, can anyone list examples of the source materials that they can be found?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the [Advanced Bestiary for Pathfinder](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Advanced_Bestiary), which brings over 100 templates for monsters and examples for each template being applied to a monster from the bestiary.

A lot of the templates on the book are [available on the templates page of the SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates) though.

A few examples being nearly all the **Dread**  templates:

- [Dread Allip (CR +3)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/dread-allip-template)
- [Dread Blood Knight (CR +3)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/dread-blood-knight-cr-3)
- [Dread Bodak (CR +2)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/dread-bodak-template)
- [Dread Devourer (CR +3)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/dread-devourer-template)
- [Dread Ghast (CR +1)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/dread-ghast-cr-1)
- [Dread Ghost (CR +3)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/dread-ghost-cr-3)
- [Dread Ghoul (CR +1)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/dread-ghoul-cr-1)

There are also bestiaries from other companies, based on specific campaign settings, which brings their own templates that are not listed on the SRD.

There is a list of nearly all third party bestiaries for pathfinder on [endzeitgeist.com](http://endzeitgeist.com/?s=bestiary&searchsubmit=):

- [Aventyr Bestiary](http://endzeitgeist.com/aventyr-bestiary/)
- [Southlands Bestiary](http://endzeitgeist.com/southlands-bestiary/)
- [Psionics Bestiary](http://endzeitgeist.com/psionic-bestiary/)

Or even the [Mythic Monster Manual from Legendary Games](http://www.makeyourgamelegendary.com/products-page/all-products/mythic-monster-manual/).

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

The answer to your question is yes, there are other sources for templates.

Some examples of these sources would be:

- The Book of Monster Templates (Rite Publishing)
- 101 Not So Simple Monster Templates (Rite Publishing)
- Southlands Bestiary (Kobold Press)